# How to get/print all max-nested non-empty subdirs starting from some path(dir)?

Tags: neovim, search, command-line, lua

How to get/print all max-nested non-empty subdirs starting from path(dir)?

I found a random option to do this on Linux (bash):

```bash
find ~/.config/nvim -type f |
sed 's%/[^/]*$%%' |
sort -u
```

But I'm looking for an os-universal neovim solution on Lua (maybe so that it would be possible to print such subdirs in a for loop)

Comment: Is there something about neovim's Lua interface that makes this neovim-specific? I suspect this is just a general programming question, but I may have misunderstood.